# Adding Bounties

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Not clear how to add bounties for questions such as [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262683/elements-of-typographic-style-subhead-styles). On my view of this question there's no *start a bounty* button. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Bounties are personal. You can basically do whatever you wish.

Comment: @percusse Thanks. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to award a bounty. As far as I recall, there used to be an _award a bounty_ option. I can't find the word bounty on the page at all.

Comment: There might be a time limit 2 days or something like that to make the link appear. I'm guessing wildly here though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty:

> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was
>   asked.

The [question you want to award a bounty for](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262683/elements-of-typographic-style-subhead-styles) was posted on 2015-08-22 at 20:45:40Z, now it's 2015-08-24 at 13:41Z. You'll be able to start a bounty in 7 hours.

There is no requirement for the question to be unanswered (one bounty reason is "to reward an existing answer").

Comment: Thanks @Jake. That must have been the reason. In a way I'm glad the system didn't let me award the bounty because now I could rephrase the problem in my [document layout styles question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262879/document-layout-styles).

Answer (score -1):

According to [FAQ about bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> If you’ve asked a good question, edited it with status and progress
>   updates, and still are not receiving answers, you can draw attention
>   to your question by placing a bounty on it.

The question linked have already received an accepted answer. So you shouldn't be enable to give one.

Comment: Thanks. I know that. As far as I know it also used to be possible to start a bounty for somebody else's question. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen : altruist bages: > First bounty you manually award on another person's question .
So I'll say yes but the question should have not received accepted answer as if you put the bounty on your own question `;-)`

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this is the reason.

Comment: Having an accepted answer is not the reason why you can't start a bounty. For example, look at the question [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/2552): it has an accepted answer, but you can still start a bounty.

Comment: @Jake yes, your right `;-)`